# Adding group layers in ArcGIS Online map?

Tags: arcgis

I want to add groups to a few layers on my ArcGIS Online map.
I am following this link:
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/add-layers-to-scene.htm

But I don't see the Create Group option at the bottom of the layers.

This is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Except for work-arounds like grouping in ArcMap as fantomen mentioned, this doesn't seem to be supported; however, there is a request for it on ArcGIS Ideas: https://community.esri.com/ideas/9987

You can "vote up" that idea to show Esri that you would like to see it implemented.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to add  group layers to ArcGIS online you need to add the layers to ArcMap and publish them to ArcGIS server. The ArcMap document name will become the group name in ArcGIS online (the name can be edited in ArcGIS Online). If you want sub groups then you can group the layers in ArcMap. In ArcGIS online you add the data as an ArcGIS server web service.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping layers are apparently not supported in ArcGIS Online webmap. The link you followed is instructions to create a web scene.

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

Grouping layers in ArcGIS Online is now possible with the new Map Viewer (which is not in beta anymore). For more info: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/try-out-layer-groups-with-map-viewer-beta/ and https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/announcements/whats-new-arcgis-online-april-2021/#mapviewer